# Install utils package in python facing with error Package not found

Tags: python, package, anaconda

I tried to install utils `Python` package using `Anaconda` but I ended up with this error:
`Package missing in current win-64 channels`

I tried:
`conda install -c bioconda utils`, but still the same. Can anyone help me fix it?

Comment: did you try  `conda install -c conda-forge python-utils`  or `conda install -c anaconda python-utils ` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try run:
`conda install --channel bioconda/label/bioconda-utils-test package`
or
`conda install -c conda-forge python-utils`

Comment: then how to use utils package? I wrote "from utils" but even after installing the package u suggested still Python throwing an error"No module named 'utils'"

Comment: @Mahyar, how did you imported `utils` in your code ?

Comment: I wrote this: "from utils import display". Since I need "display" in utils package

Answer (score 2):

Install:

```
pip install utils
```

Import:

```
import utils
```

Answer (score 1):

to install run:

```
pip install python-utils
```

to import:

```
import python_utils
```

worked fine on jupyter notebook ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0):

I succeed using following instructions:

The package can be installed through pip (this is the recommended method):

```
pip install python-utils
```

Or if pip is not available, easy_install should work as well:

```
easy_install python-utils
```

for more details please refer to https://pypi.org/project/python-utils/

however, I failed using Влад Давидченко's answers.

Answer (score -1):

Once you have installed python-utils with:

```
conda install --name myenv python-utils
```

You can then reference the package by using:

```
from python_utils import *
```